# The user is navigated to the 'ProfessorPage()' even when the userType is 'Student'

Tags: flutter, dart

I was building this flutter app when I detected a problem. The user is navigated to the ProfessorPage() after logging in, even when the userType is Student. Only after restarting the app or hitting the hot reload does the StudentPage() open up. What is causing the problem?

```
import 'dart:io';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:com.institutioncode.professor/loading.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'Professor/professor_page.dart';
import 'welcome.dart';
import 'Student/student_page.dart';
import 'firebase_config.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print('Initialising the app...');

  // Wrap the Firebase initialization code block with a try-catch block
  try {
    await initializeFirebase(
      options: FirebaseOptions(
        appId: ####
            ? ''
            : Platform.isAndroid
                ? '####'
                : '####',
        apiKey: '####',
        projectId: '####',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        databaseURL:
            '####', // Firebase Realtime Database URL
      ),
    );
    print('Firebase initialised successfully...');

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final loggedIn = prefs.getBool('loggedIn') ?? false;
    final userType = prefs.getString('userType') ?? 'Unknown';

    if (loggedIn) {
      final user = User(userType: userType);
      runApp(MyApp(loggedIn: true, user: user));
    } else {
      runApp(MyApp(loggedIn: false));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Firebase initialization failed: $e');
    // Handle the error as needed
  }
}

class User {
  final String userType;
  User({this.userType = 'Unknown'});
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool loggedIn;
  final User? user;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.loggedIn, this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Widget initialPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.loggedIn) {
      if (widget.user == null) {
        // User object is not yet fully initialized, show a loading screen
        initialPage = const LoadingPage();
      } else {
        updateInitialPage();
      }
    } else {
      initialPage = Welcome();
      print('Returning to Welcome Screen 2...');
    }
  }

  void updateInitialPage() {
    if (widget.user?.userType == 'Student') {
      print('Identified as a Student...');
      initialPage = const StudentPage();
    } else if (widget.user?.userType == 'Professor') {
      print('Identified as a Professor...');
      initialPage = const ProfessorPage();
    } else {
      initialPage = Welcome();
      print('Returning to Welcome Screen 1...');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Institution Code',
      theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 239, 239, 239)),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => initialPage,
        '/login': (context) => Welcome(),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyApp oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.loggedIn) {
      if (widget.user == null) {
        // User object is not yet fully initialized, show a loading screen
        setState(() {
          initialPage = const LoadingPage();
        });
      } else {
        updateInitialPage();
        setState(() {});
      }
    } else {
      initialPage = Welcome();
      print('Returning to Welcome Screen 4...');
    }
  }
}
```

I tried different ways to navigate the user correctly without having to restart or reload the app, but that won't help. What is causing the problem & how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the login and signup pages. They were by default set to navigate to the ProfessorPage(). But after the app was restarted, the main() takes control, which navigates the user based on the `userType`.

The solution here was to add `if-else statements` to the login and signup pages to navigate based on the fetched `userType`.

Answer (score 0):

try this little modification here :

class _MyAppState extends State {
late Widget initialPage = const LoadingPage();

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.loggedIn && widget.user != null) {
      updateInitialPage();
    }
  }

  void updateInitialPage() {
    if (widget.user!.userType == 'Student') {
      initialPage = const StudentPage();
    } else if (widget.user!.userType == 'Professor') {
      initialPage = const ProfessorPage();
    } else {
      initialPage = Welcome();
      print('Returning to Welcome Screen 1...');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Institution Code',
      theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 239, 239, 239)),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => initialPage,
        '/login': (context) => Welcome(),
      },
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyApp oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.loggedIn && widget.user != null) {
      updateInitialPage();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```